# How to do a properly code method to show when tap 1 to 10 with a if condition

Tags: ios, swift

I really need your help, I thought 2 hours around a method to use to get my code better but I didn't find... I want to display a popup when I tap for exemple 5 a specific popup by number so I can use if field == 1 and repeat against arrive to 10 for exemple but he doesn't appear good and it's too deprecated. So here's the entire code of the concerned asking:

I hope you will understand what I want I think that's simple but anyway I would your help to improve my skills and my work.

I just want to use a better way to show and write the code.

```
  func changeLog1P(){
    let changeLog1P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog1P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog1P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog2P(){
    let changeLog2P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog2P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog2P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog3P(){
    let changeLog3P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog3P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog3P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog4P(){
    let changeLog4P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog4P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog4P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog5P(){
    let changeLog5P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog5P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog5P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog6P(){
    let changeLog6P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog6P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog6P, animated: true)
}

func changeLog7P(){
    let changeLog7P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build 1", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog7P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog7P, animated: true)
}

func errorBuildNumber(){
    let errorBuildNumberP = UIAlertController(title: "Build number incorrect", message: "Le build number que vous avez entré n'est pas conforme ou n'est pas correct, assurez-vous d'avoir :\n\n- Choisi un nombre décimal\n- Choisi un nombre positif non nul\n- Choisi un nombre sans virgule ni caractères spéciaux", preferredStyle: .alert)
    errorBuildNumberP.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Réésayer", style: .cancel, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.changelogPopup()
    }))

    self.present(errorBuildNumberP, animated: true)
}

func changelogPopup(){
    let changeLog1 = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG", message: "Veuillez choisir la version pour laquelle vous souhaitez voir le changelog :", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog1.addAction(UIAlertAction (title: "Continuer", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

        let field = changeLog1.textFields?[0] as! UITextField
        let textfieldInt: Int! = Int(field.text!)
        if (textfieldInt <= self.appVersion && textfieldInt >= 1){
            if field.text == "1"{
                self.changeLog1P()
            }
            if field.text == "2"{
                self.changeLog2P()
            }
            if field.text == "3"{
                self.changeLog3P()
            }
            if field.text == "4"{
                self.changeLog4P()
            }
            if field.text == "5"{
                self.changeLog5P()
            }
            if field.text == "6"{
                self.changeLog6P()
            }
            if field.text == "7"{
                self.changeLog7P()
            }
        }else{
            self.errorBuildNumber()
        }
    }))
    changeLog1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuler", style: .cancel, handler: nil))


    changeLog1.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Numéro de Build de la version"
        changeLog1.textFields![0].keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad

    }

    self.present(changeLog1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you for helping me,

Louis.

Comment: Sorry but this is unclear. To start, why do all seven of your `changeLogXP` functions do exactly the same thing?

Comment: No, I know this is no optimized, I do that because I want to show a popup for any build of my app for example any build contains different modifications and news or improvements so I need to show a different popup for any new Build

Comment: But you are not showing different popups. They are all the same. They all have the same title and message. If you want help then you need to show how they are different.

Comment: I know in the code there's the same message I will modify it later it's not important I want to know how to get my code better without create func for every build and even say when you have in 1 and 10 you will find the correct popup and show it, for example I don't want to use if ... == 1 then if again and again up to 10 for example I think this is a for cond

Comment: Start by putting configurable data to resources, that means all your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func changelogPopup(){
    let changeLog1 = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG", message: "Veuillez choisir la version pour laquelle vous souhaitez voir le changelog :", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog1.addAction(UIAlertAction (title: "Continuer", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

    let field = changeLog1.textFields?[0] as! UITextField
    let textfieldInt: Int! = Int(field.text!)
    if (textfieldInt <= self.appVersion && textfieldInt >= 1){
        //MINE
        self.changeLog1P(number: field.text)

        //YOURS
        /*
        if field.text == "1"{
            self.changeLog1P()
        }
        if field.text == "2"{
            self.changeLog2P()
        }
        if field.text == "3"{
            self.changeLog3P()
        }
        if field.text == "4"{
            self.changeLog4P()
        }
        if field.text == "5"{
            self.changeLog5P()
        }
        if field.text == "6"{
            self.changeLog6P()
        }
        if field.text == "7"{
            self.changeLog7P()
        }*/
    }else{
        self.errorBuildNumber()
    }
}))

//Add a parameter to take in
func changeLog1P(number:String){
    //Add the variable inside a string using "\()" wherever you'd like.
    let changeLog1P = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG V1.0 Build \(number)", message: "- Modifications et nouveautés -\n\n- Première version déployée", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog1P.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(changeLog1P, animated: true)
}
```

Your example isn't really good because I can't see what you want changed because everything is the same.

Comment: I know in the code there's the same message I will modify it later it's not important I want to know how to get my code better without create func for every build and even say when you have in 1 and 10 you will find the correct popup and show it, for example I don't want to use if ... == 1 then if again and again up to 10 for example I think this is a for cond. EDIT: I already answered your question I'm sorry for the unclearance of my ask

Comment: Thank you for your answer I understand what you did, I will try to do that with a number to the func

Comment: Thank you I find by myself.